# How to customize swiftui file exporter to show save instead of move

Tags: ios, swift, file, swiftui, export

I would like to allow user to export a text file and save it to their filesystem. However, swiftUI shows a button that says move in the popupview instead of save. how can I change that behavior.

[image]

```swift
struct FileExporterDemo: View {
    @State private var showingExporter = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("export"){showingExporter = true}
        .fileExporter(isPresented: $showingExporter, document: TextFile(initialText: "test"), contentType: .plainText) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                print("Saved to \(url)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow us to change title of navigationBar items for FileExporter because it is using System preferences as mentioned in [offical document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fileexporter(ispresented:document:contenttype:defaultfilename:oncompletion:)-32vwk).

```
func fileExporter<C>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, documents: C, contentType: UTType, onCompletion: (Result<[URL], Error>) -> Void) -> some View
```

Presents a **system interface** for allowing the user to export a collection of in-memory documents to files on disk.